# Como alterar o conteúdo de uma variável a cada 30 minutos

Tags: php

O código abaixo faz com que o e-mail seja enviado especificamente para um determinado e-mail especificado na variável `$email_remetente` e basicamente se a hora for maior que a especificado na função: `$dates->setTime(13,30,00);` ele envia para outro e-mail.

A ideia seria que a cada 30 minutos ele alterasse a variável `$email_remetente` para um e-mail e depois de 30 minutos voltar para outro e-mail.

```
<?php

 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i');

$email_remetente = "suporte1@email.com"; 

 //altera email do remetente de acordo com a hora

 $dates = new \DateTime();

$dates->setTime(13,30,00);

$dateNows = new \DateTime();



if($dateNows > $dates) {
    $email_remetente = 'suporte2@email.com';
}

?>
```

Comment: "se a hora for maior que a especificado na função" ... um IF não resolve !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa noite. Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas acredito que você quer implementar uma espécie de turnos para os emails de suporte, de modo que, a cada 30 minutos, é o outro que entra em ação. Se for isso mesmo, existem várias formas de fazer isso.
Se só existirem dois emails, você enviará para o primeiro sempre que os minutos forem menores que 30 e para o outro sempre que forem maiores ou iguais.
Então, implementando:

```
<?php
$minuto = (int) date('i');
$email = ($minuto < 30) ? "email1@example.com" : "email2@example.com";
// ...
```

Assim, os emails serão:

- 10h29 → email1
- 10h30 → email2
- 10h55 → email2
- 11h00 → email1
- ...

Se quiser fazer de maneira dinâmica, você pode definir um array com o horário de início para cada email e percorrê-lo para escolher o mais próximo.